# Assignment in conditional not permitted in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

Why is code like

```
if a = "hello":
    pass
```

invalid in Python? The a = "Hello" is just a expression whose value is the Rvalue. It's valid in most languages like C or php. Some opinions?

Comment: If you tell your C compiler to emit warnings, it'd warn you while making an _assignment_ in a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intentionally made illegal in python as allowing it is a huge source of error and making it illegal is a minor inconvenience.

See [the Design and History FAQ](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-can-t-i-use-an-assignment-in-an-expression)

My experience in python is that this is basically right.  I rarely miss not being able to do this.

Answer (score 2):

While Python will allow you to chain assignment,

```
a = b = "hello"
```

it will not allow you to use it in an expression,

```
"hi" > b = "hello"    # => Syntax error
```

This is for safety, to keep you from accidentally using = when you meant ==

Comment: thanks a lot. It really confused me when the a = b = "hello" is valid while the if a = "hello is invalid. But I don't think it is necessary for experienced developers.