# if statement with inline assignment in python3 ( assignment expression )

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, variable-assignment, inline

Given the following statement in python (3):

```
import math
for i in range(100):
    if((result = math.factorial(i)) % 10  == 0):
        print(i,"->",result)
```

Isn't it possible (like in C)?

Comment: No, that's not possible in Python. In addition, it's bad practice even in languages that do allow it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assignment in conditional not permitted in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600575/assignment-in-conditional-not-permitted-in-python)

Comment: The referred link raises the same question as I put, but it doesn't supply a solution. An answer below supplies the solution in form of the "walrus" operator.

Answer (score 5):

This is called assignment expression and has been made possible by the introduction of the walrus operator `:=` in Python 3.8:

```py
import math
for i in range(100):
    if (result := math.factorial(i)) % 10 == 0:
        print(i, "->", result)
```

Note however that its use is not without controversy. Always aim for readable and understandable code. The above is rather dense and would benefit from a local variable in the loop body:

```py
import math
for i in range(100):
    result = math.factorial(i)
    if result % 10 == 0:
        print(i, "->", result)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying about "benefit from a local variable"? So my "dense version" would benefit from a local variable?

Comment: @Krischu the readability benefits from it because the complex statement gets broken down into two statements that are much easier to understand, debug and modify

Comment: @Krischu have I answered your question? If I solved your issue, please consider marking the answer as accepted. Otherwise, let me know how else I can help!